# Gray background in start menu on Windows 10 20H2

Tags: uwp, windows-10

On Windows 10 up to 20H1 my UWP app "RECOIL" looks like this in the start menu:

[image: 20h1]

On Windows 10 20H2 instead of the teal background that I selected there's a light gray background:

[image: 20h2]

How do I get rid of the light gray background, like Access and Acrobat Reader DC do?

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="RECOIL"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
    Description="Shows images in native formats of vintage computers"
    BackgroundColor="#006374">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
</uap:VisualElements>
```

The assets are the white "R" letter on a fully transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get rid of the light gray background, like Access and Acrobat Reader DC do?

The light gray background of the app icon is plated. If you want to use unplated assets, please refer [**Unplated assets**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#unplated-assets) document.

> By default, Windows uses a target-based asset on top of a colored backplate by default. If you want, you can provide a target-based unplated asset. "Unplated" means the asset will be displayed on a transparent background. Keep in mind that these assets will appear over a variety of background colors.

The size recommendations for target-based assets, at 100% scale: unplated 24px icon, and the default plated 16px icon on 24px plate. Please go to `Visual Assets-> App icon -> set unplated assets for your app`.

We suggest you generate app' assets with Asset Generator. For more please refer App logo [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos).